# How to set height:auto to works with div wihtout use a float:left?

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

Look,

I tried to do this, but I'm tired.

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="external" style="margin: 0 auto; height:auto; border:1px solid #ccc;">
<div class="mycontent">
X, Y
<br/>
Z, W
</div>
</div>
```

What I want is that the "external" div have the height of "mycontent" div, but it only works when "external" has float:left defined in the styles. I cannot use "float:left" because I need the "external" div be centered always.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you try a clearfix?

Comment: Did you try overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 0):

The height of the `#external` div is already the same height as the `.mycontent` div.

Run this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QsXxD/) and all you will see is the orange background I set for the `.mycontent` div and not the blue background I set for the `#external` div.

If you want the `#external` div to essentially wrap the `.mycontent` div vertically and horizontally, while at the same time being centered in the screen, use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

[**See jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/43jVZ/)

---

### HTML

```
<div id="external">
    <div class="mycontent">
        X, Y
        <br/>
        Z, W
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### CSS

```
#external 
{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    background: blue;         /* for demo purposes */
}
.mycontent 
{
    display: table-cell;
    background: orange;       /* for demo purposes */
    color: white;             /* for demo purposes */
}
```